# Images added through GUI not serialized as Blob (Sitecore 7.5/Unicorn)

Tags: serialization, sitecore, blob, sitecore-unicorn

If we add an image through the `Upload Media` action inside Sitecore Rocks, the image will serialize completely with all the binary data it needs to be reproduced:

```
----field----
field: {40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}
name: Blob
key: blob
content-length: 46816

R0lGOD... /*Binary data here*/
```

However, when we try adding an image through the Sitecore GUI, the image is not stored as binary data and cannot be given to others. It simply holds a path:

```
----field----
field: {40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}
name: Blob
key: blob
content-length: 46816

/static/files/media_files/2/2/4/{22481B01-4210-413A-AABB-5A7EE3387D7F}some-imge-file.png
```

How do we get the Sitecore GUI to store it the same way as Rocks?

We are one 7.5 using Unicorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like your config is set to store images as files rather than in the database. Check the following setting to see if it is true or false:

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false">
```

See this post for more information: http://firebreaksice.com/storing-sitecore-media-in-the-database-vs-the-file-system/

Alternatively, do you have any customization in the media upload dialogs?

Comment: I checked the global `web.config` in our project and you are correct in that the value is set to `true` there. The problem we now face is that this is a multi-site instance in which we are not able to change global files. I tried to add the setting into our more specific `web.config` file but it does not seem to pick it up. Any idea as to why? Or is this not something that can be changed on a per-directory/`web.config` basis?

Comment: No - the sitecore section of the config I believe it read on AppStart and merged with all the config files in /App_Config/Include, so you wouldn't be able to change on a per-directory basis. You may be able to add a custom include file and patch the setting, or you might have to write some custom code to have that setting change on a per-site bases. Perhaps based on a setting in the Site Definition.  Any change via an include file, would affect every site in the instance.